# Java: MouseListener does not register when objects move on screen

Tags: java, events, mouse, listener, mouselistener

I am making a simple game where a red ball and a blue ball move across the screen at a random speed along the x-axis (and a constant speed across the y axis).  The player scores points by clicking on the balls, which resets their position and adds points to the player's score based on the speed the ball was moving along the x-axis.  I have implemented a MouseListener to track the player's actions.  When the ball movement is commented out, the MouseListener registers everything perfectly.  When the balls are allowed to move, the MouseListener will only register at seemingly random intervals.  I don't believe it is a hit detection problem anymore, because the program plays a sound whether you hit or you miss, and when the MouseListener is failing to register no sound plays.

Code:

Main Class

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends Applet implements Runnable, MouseListener{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526472295622776147L; 

    private int speed;

    boolean isStopped=true;

    private Player player;
    private Ball redball;
    private Ball blueball;

    Thread t;

    AudioClip shotnoise;
    AudioClip hitnoise;
    AudioClip outnoise;

    Font f = new Font ("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20);

    Cursor c;

    private Image dbImage;
    private Graphics dbg;

    public void init(){
        this.addMouseListener(this);

        setSize(400,400);

        c=new Cursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR);
        this.setCursor(c);

        setBackground (Color.black);

        setFont (f);

        if (getParameter ("speed") != null)
        {
            speed = Integer.parseInt(getParameter("speed"));
        }
        else speed = 15;

        hitnoise = getAudioClip (getCodeBase() , "gun.au");
        hitnoise.play();
        hitnoise.stop();
        shotnoise = getAudioClip (getCodeBase() , "miss.au");
        shotnoise.play();
        shotnoise.stop();
        outnoise = getAudioClip (getCodeBase() , "error.au");
        outnoise.play();
        outnoise.stop();

        player = new Player ();
        redball = new Ball (10, 190, 250, 1, -1, 4, Color.red, outnoise, player);
        blueball = new Ball (10, 190, 150, 1, 1, 3, Color.blue, outnoise, player);
    }

    public void start ()
    {
        t = new Thread (this);
        t.start ();
    }

    public void stop ()
    {
    }

    public void run(){
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);

        while(true){
            if(player.getLives()>=0 && !isStopped){
                redball.move();
                blueball.move();
            }

            repaint();

            try{
                Thread.sleep(speed);
            }

            catch(InterruptedException e){
            }

            Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        if(player.getLives()>=0){
            g.setColor(Color.yellow);

            g.drawString("Score: " + player.getScore(),10,40);
            g.drawString("Lives: "+ player.getLives(), 300, 40);

            redball.DrawBall(g);
            blueball.DrawBall(g);

            if(isStopped){
                g.setColor(Color.yellow);

                g.drawString("Double Click to Start",40, 200);
            }
        }
        else if(player.getLives()<0){
            g.setColor(Color.yellow);

            g.drawString("Game Over!",130,100);
            g.drawString("You Scored: "+player.getScore()+"Points!",90, 140);

            if (player.getScore() < 300) g.drawString ("Well, it could be better!", 100, 190);
            else if (player.getScore() < 600 && player.getScore() >= 300) g.drawString ("That was not so bad", 100, 190);
            else if (player.getScore() < 900 && player.getScore() >= 600) g.drawString ("That was really good", 100, 190);
            else if (player.getScore() < 1200 && player.getScore() >= 900) g.drawString ("You seem to be very good!", 90, 190);
            else if (player.getScore() < 1500 && player.getScore() >= 1200) g.drawString ("That was nearly perfect!", 90, 190);
            else if (player.getScore() >= 1500) g.drawString ("You are the Champingon!",100, 190);

            g.drawString("Double Click on the Applet to Play Again!",20,220);

            isStopped=true;
        }
    }

    public void update(Graphics g){
        if(dbImage==null){
            dbImage=createImage(this.getSize().width,this.getSize().height);
            dbg=dbImage.getGraphics();
        }

        dbg.setColor(getBackground());
        dbg.fillRect(0,0,this.getSize().width,this.getSize().height);

        dbg.setColor(getForeground());
        paint(dbg);

        g.drawImage(dbImage,0,0,this);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        if(!isStopped){
            if(redball.userHit(e.getX(),e.getY())){
                hitnoise.play();

                redball.wasHit();
            }

            else if (blueball.userHit (e.getX(),e.getY())){
                hitnoise.play();

                blueball.wasHit();
            }
            else{
                shotnoise.play();
            }
        }
        else if(isStopped&&e.getClickCount()==2){
            isStopped=false;
            init();
        }
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
    }
}
```

Ball Class

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Ball{
    private int x_pos;
    private int y_pos;
    private int x_speed;
    private int y_speed;
    private int radius;

    private int first_x;
    private int first_y;

    private int max_speed;

    private final int x_leftout = 10;
    private final int x_rightout = 370;
    private final int y_upout = 45;
    private final int y_downout = 370;

    Color color;

    AudioClip out;

    Player player;

    Random rnd=new Random();

    public Ball(int radius, int x, int y, int vx, int vy, int ms, Color color, AudioClip out, Player player){
        this.radius=radius;

        x_pos=x;
        y_pos=y;

        first_x=x;
        first_y=y;

        x_speed=vx;
        y_speed=vy;

        max_speed = ms;

        this.color = color;

        this.out = out;

        this.player = player;
    }

    public void move(){
        x_pos+= x_speed;
        y_pos+=y_speed;
        isOut();
    }

    public void wasHit(){
        x_pos = first_x;
        y_pos = first_y;

        x_speed = (rnd.nextInt ()) % max_speed;
    }

    private boolean isOut(){
        if(x_pos>x_rightout){
            x_pos=first_x;
            y_pos=first_y;

            out.play();

            x_speed=(rnd.nextInt())%max_speed;

            player.looseLife();

            return true;
        }
        else if(x_pos<x_leftout){
            x_pos=first_x;
            y_pos=first_y;

            out.play();

            x_speed=(rnd.nextInt())%max_speed;

            player.looseLife();

            return true;
        }
        else if(y_pos>y_downout){
            x_pos=first_x;
            y_pos=first_y;

            out.play();

            x_speed=(rnd.nextInt())%max_speed;

            player.looseLife();

            return true;
        }
        else if(y_pos<y_upout){
            x_pos=first_x;
            y_pos=first_y;

            out.play();

            x_speed=(rnd.nextInt())%max_speed;

            player.looseLife();

            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    public boolean userHit(int mouse_x, int mouse_y){
        int dx=Math.abs(x_pos-mouse_x);
        int dy=Math.abs(y_pos-mouse_y);

        if(dx>radius){
            return false;
        }
        else if(dy>radius){
            return false;
        }
        else{ 
            player.AddScore(10*Math.abs(x_speed)+10);
            return true;
        }

    }

    public void DrawBall (Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor (color);
        g.fillOval (x_pos - radius, y_pos - radius, 2*radius, 2*radius);
    }
}
```

Player Class

```
public class Player{
    private int lives;
    private int score;

    public Player(){
        lives=10;
        score=0;
    }

    public int getScore(){
        return score;
    }

    public int getLives(){
        return lives;
    }

    public void looseLife(){
        lives--;
    }

    public void AddScore(int points){
        score+=points;
    }
}
```

Comment: Playing clips in the GUI thread is time consuming.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Should I just edit out all the back story then, or would it be better to start a new question with all of it edited out?  I only added it because before posting the site advised me to make it clear how much research I had done beforehand.  Admittedly, I don't think I even accomplished that.

Comment: Don't start a new question unless you want to upset folks. Instead clean this question by telling us what we need to know to be able to answer it, and by creating and posting an SSCCE as requested above.

Comment: AWT and not Swing because my tutorials haven't explained what Swing is yet.  I didn't even know there was another option.  I also pasted in all of my code because I have absolutely no idea where the problem is.

Comment: Cross-posted [java-forums.org](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/62284-java-mouselistener-does-not-register-when-objects-move-screen.html)

Comment: Yes, I was just informed about this there as well.  I hadn't considered it might be rude.  I thought if I posted it in two places I might get an answer faster.  I apologize.  Here is the link to the double-post: http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/62284-java-mouselistener-does-not-register-when-objects-move-screen.html

Comment: Since the original purpose of this project was to learn how java coding works, and I only half feel I have learned anything at all, I am moving on to a different java tutorial at this point and will no longer be checking for answers here.